# How to make an list style array echo

Tags: php, arrays, yaml

I am working on trying to get [spyc](https://github.com/mustangostang/spyc) working but I keep running into the same problem, whenever I run my code:

```
<?php
    include('spyc.php');

    $array = array (
        'groups'  => array(
            'default' => array(
                'permissions' => array(
                    'perm.node.one' => true,
                    'perm.node.two' => true
                    )
                )
            )
    );
    print_r($array);
    $yaml = Spyc::YAMLDump($array);
    echo $yaml;
?>
```

It works but the result isnt displaying right. This is what I get:

```
Array ( [groups] => Array ( [default] => Array ( [permissions] => Array ( [perm.node.one] => 1 [perm.node.two] => 1 ) ) ) ) groups: default: permissions: perm.node.one: true perm.node.two: true
```

I should be getting:

```
Array
(
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [default] => Array
                (
                    [permissions] => Array
                        (
                        [perm.node.one] => 1
                        [perm.node.two] => 1 
                        )

                )

        )

)
YAML Data dumped back:
groups:
  default:
    permissions:
      perm.node.one: true
      perm.node.two: true
```

What I need is how organized it is. I cant seem to get that. Iv been looking all over. I tried `array_chunk()` but with no luck. Any help would be great! Thank you very much.

Comment: wrap it up with `<pre>` html tag

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the function : `Spyc::YAMLDump` is returning the line wrap under the format `\r\n`.

If you want to see it correctly in the html format, just use the tag `<pre></pre>` around your dump.

By the way, if you look at the source code (CTRL + U under Mozilla or Chrome), your dump should be correctly indented without the `<pre></pre>` !